# In android How to share attrs between custom views

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-resources

I created many custom Views and any of views has a custom attribute: mystyle.

so that in my attr.xml:

```
<resources> 
    <declare-styleable name="MyView1">
         <attr name="mystyle" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="MyView2">
         <attr name="mystyle" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="MyView2">
         <attr name="mystyle" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
     ...
</resources>
```

I think that's not grace. Is there any way to use one attr for all the custome view?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make `abstract ParentView` and declare attribute for it. Then all your custom views will extend `ParentView`, and attribute will be declared